# Encoding Issue with data from MySQL database

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, mojibake

I have a sql database that has encoding issues, so it's returning me a result that is similar to this:

```
"CuvÃ©e"
```

From what I can tell this is because it was encoded to latin-1 when it should have been encoded to UTF-8 (please correct me if I'm wrong). I'm processing these results in a Python script and have been getting a few encoding problems and have been unable to convert it back to what it's supposed to be:

```
"Cuvée"
```

I'm using Python 3.3 but by using codecs.decode to make the change from latin1 to utf-8 I'm getting:

```
'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I think I've tried everything I found to no avail. I'm not really keen on going to Python 2.7 because I've written the rest of the script on 3.3 and it will be quite a pain to rewrite. Is there a way to do this that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have what is called a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); it could be Latin-1, or it could be [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or another closely related codec.

You *could* just try to encode as Latin-1, then decode again:

```
faulty_text.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

However, sometimes, especially with CP1252 Mojibakes, the faulty encoding results in text that cannot *legally* be encoded back to bytes, because some UTF-8 bytes were 'decoded' forcefully even though the codec doesn't support those bytes.

Your best bet is to install the [`ftfy` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftfy), which can *automatically* fix such Mojibake mistakes for you. It includes special codecs to undo CP1252 Mojibakes properly (as well as other related codepages), codecs that bypass the aforementioned problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to bytes first and then decoding the unicode. Based on your example:

```
latin_string = "CuvÃ©e"
# Get a byte representation of the latin string
bytes(latin_string,'latin-1')
b'Cuv\xc3\xa9e' # Note the preceding b
# Get a byte representation and decode the utf-8 to get a 'pretty' string
bytes(latin1string,'latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'Cuvée'
```